How to set width of vtkAxisActor2D?
I am using vtkLegendScaleActor as following:
scaleActor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLegendScaleActor>::New();
scaleActor->RightAxisVisibilityOff();
scaleActor->LeftAxisVisibilityOff();
scaleActor->TopAxisVisibilityOff();
scaleActor->LegendVisibilityOff();

auto bottomAxis = scaleActor->GetBottomAxis();
bottomAxis->SetWidth(0.3333);

I want the bottomAxis to be 1/3rd of the viewport width. Instead of the desired effect the Axis becomes extremely large. Going off of the screen as pictured below.
If I do not set width takes up .75 of the viewport and it looks fine but I need it to be smaller.

